# CFEngine. I want to distribute a set of files which are different for different versions of ubuntu for eg 13.04 and 14.04.

Tags: configuration-management, cfengine

I googled it up and read through but did'nt find any answer. I am using cfengine-community 3.5 version on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different subdirectory trees for each of the versions of Ubuntu that you're dealing with; i.e.:

```
/data/cfengine3/data/ubuntu-13.04
/data/cfengine3/data/ubuntu-14.04
...
```

Then define one class per version of Ubuntu (ubuntu_13_04, ubuntu_14_04...) and execute the copying of files of one subdirectory or the other, depending on the class that is defined.

We do it like this, because we still have a small set of servers with CentOS 5.